# Azure Container App ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-container-apps

I have multiple microservices running as Azure Container Apps. I am a bit confused about how the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is managed. For example, locally, I can change launchsettings.json or Windows Env variables etc... and restart the app to reflect the change. But when running in Container Apps, what's the best way to handle it?

Currently each microservice configuration is in Azure App Configuration grouped by a key (microservice assembly name). May be I can have an environment entry for each service where I change it and restart the container app?

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) talks about Azure App Services but couldn't find any information related to Container Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to create and deploy a new revision, you actually can specify the environment variables for the container instance in the dialog,

[image]

and that's where you should set `ASPNET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT` if you want.